# program crashes while running linked list program

Tags: c++, linked-list

this is the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
        int data;
        Node *next;
};
Node *head;

`insert function takes a number as argument`
void insert(int a)
{
        Node *temp = new Node();
        temp -> data= a;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;

}

void print(void)
{
        Node *temp1;
        temp1 = head;
        while(head != NULL)
  {

      cout<<temp1->data<<endl;
      temp1 = temp1->next;

  }
}
**main function**
int main()
{
        head = NULL;
        int a;
        int b;
        cout<<"how many elements do you want to insert";
        cin>>b;
        for (int i = 0;i < b; i++)
    {
         cout<<"enter a number"<<endl;
         cin>>a;
         insert(a);
         print();
    }
        return 0;
}
```

when I enter the number to insert it shows **program has stopped working**. I am trying to insert numbers to linked list and print it ever time I add a number.I have checked for many other errors but it has none.

Comment: `while(head != NULL)` will never end. You could have easily found this by stepping through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Unrelated: `insert` function could be a one-liner. `head = new node{ a, head };` This takes advantage of [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

Comment: Also unrelated: I'm tired of seeing C-style linked lists under C++. Make an actual template class, write iterators for it, etc. Writing a proper linked list in C++ is a great way to exercise a wide variety of C++ principles and practices. This is busy work.

Comment: Unrelated: You should have a guard on `cin>>a;` in case some fool types a letter or something else that isn't a valid part of an `int`. Something like `if (cin>>a) { insert (a); } else {cin.clear(); cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); i--; }` would work, but it's probably better to change the loop type  aand have it iterate until the count of valid inputs reaches `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might be due to an infinite loop like one of the comments says. Try updating the loop in the `print` function like this:

```
void print() {
    Node *temp1;
    temp1 = head;

    // Here, I switched `head` with `temp1`
    while (temp1 != nullptr) {
        std::cout << temp1->data << std::endl;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }
}
```